# Installing toe kick on bathroom vanity

Tags: bathroom, vanity

Installed a bathroom vanity with one side up against the wall. Our baseboards are tapered from top to bottom. Do we install the toe kick up to the baseboard or do we install the toe kick to the wall and the baseboard installed to the toe kick?

Comment: The baseboard will go up to the toe kick as the vanity is in its own defined space. Imagine it as a complete wall to ceiling corner box. Therefore your vanity and toe kick would be installed and the baseboard would be mounted up to the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Install the toe kick to the wall and the baseboard to the toe kick